# Why does a mentos make soda explode?

Tags: experimental-chemistry

So if you put a mint mentos in a cup of soda it will explode everywhere. The mint in the mentos makes the soda have a chemical reaction which will then make the soda explode right? Well what would happen if we put a mento in different types of soda would that make a difference in how much chemical reation there will be? I already put mentos in cream soda and it made a small explosion. So I wondering if the different sodas had different effects on  how big the explosions are.

Comment: Don’t think it’s a chemical reaction. More so that it creates nucleation sites that drive CO2 out of solution I believe.

Comment: When you open the soda bottle, the CO2 present in solution must get out, as the pressure is suddenlyvery  low. But to get out, nucleation sites are needed, that is bumps or rough edges of something, around which the bubbles can be formed.  The pill do have a lot. So the bubbles are formed all of a sudden around the pill. It looks like an explosion, but it is not. 

The only trouble is that nobody has ever explained why this phenomena is so important with a Mentos pill in Coca light. Other pills or other sodas
do not work so violently.

Comment: @Maurice must be that the structure of mentos leads to a larger surface plus, perhaps, a special wax or so more affine with CO2 but just the right amount. Logic says that others similar products should do the same with the same violence.

Comment: Comparison between sodas. Unfortunately the surface is fixed. https://www.compoundchem.com/2017/05/02/coke-mentos/amp/

Comment: @Alchimista. Why is the explosion stronger with Coca Light than with regular Coca ? And why does it not work so strongly with Pepsi or other sodas ? Or Mineral water ? Nobody knows !

Comment: what do you mean the surface is fixed

Comment: @puppylover the "catalitic" surface, being the experiment in the link just using mentos.

Comment: @Maurice that is why I've linked the poster. From that page one finds ref to an experiment using different sodas and (trying) linking composition to fountain height.